# Running C# project with ms-access-database which is accessable on a network

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, ms-access

I have a C#-project (windows form application - developed with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10) that uses a ms-access database which is located on a network. In my project I access to the ms-access database by using the following code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=some\datapaht\TEST_21.accdb");
```

No I want to run the application on the target-machine that has the access to this datapath on my network. However my target-machine does not have  ms-access installed.

My question :

Is it enough to just copy the project file to the target-machine and open the .exe-file which is already in my porject-file? Or do I need to take further steps than just copying the project-file to make the programm runable on the target-machine?  What do I need else?

My target-machine has windows 7 installed.

In my project I read and write into the ms-access database.

I think it is not that easy than it seems to be ?!

Thank you !

EDIT:

I found out that I need to make sure that the right ms-ACE-OLEDB version and .NET Framework version are installed on my target machine. In this case I can run the .exe-file in my project file without any issues. Well I am not sure regarding writing into my database. However reading works perfectly.

LATEST EDIT:

Writing data works also perfectly. However I assume that it is not the best way to do as I do. However I would be happy if somone is able to give me some advices how to do it on a safer way!

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What worked? What did not work?

Comment: Well, I am not done yet with developing. There some features that have to be added to my project. However I wanted to know what I have to consider. What I know is that it is possible to add the database-file directly to my project-file by set up the the project (there some tutorials  online that show step by step instruction). What I want is to have the access database not in my project.

Comment: If I run the exe on my machine it works perfectly  without having any issues. But on my machine I have ms-access installed and visual studio 2017 as well.

Comment: And I also know that I have to consider an engine that is called ACE which allows me to manage some services regarding ms-access database. But I have to make sure that the same engine is installed on the target machine. As far as I understood.